# C++ auto keyword when using initialize list

Tags: c++

I have a question for using of key word auto when I run code below:

```
auto i_num = {1};
printf("%x", i_num);//61fecc
return 0;
```

I think it's the same as below but not:

```
int i_num = {1};
printf("%x", i_num);//1
return 0;
```

Can anyone explain this difference to me? It seems auto i_num and  int i_num define different things.

Comment: *I think it's the same as below...* `61fecc` ≠ `1`.  `std::initializer_list<int>` ≠ `int`.

Comment: the first one should be an array that contains just one element, the second one treats the {1} as an integer initialization and it just sets the value of i_num to it as i_num is declared as int

Comment: Try `auto i_num{1};`

Comment: it might be different based on the architecture of the processor or even a micro controller and its compiler.

Comment: This is the famous [change made in C++14](http://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp14.dcl.dcl#2). `auto i{1};` was changed to be an int, but `auto i = {1};` is still an initializer_list. A "good" compromise...

Comment: Your compiler should warn about the mismatch of `std::printf`'s format string (if not, you've failed to enable enough warnings).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `auto i_num = {1}` defines a variable with type `std::initializer_list<int>`.
You should have a warning from the compiler about the fact that you are trying to print an initializer list using the `%x` format.
It prints the address of the first item in the initializer list (not the initializer list address).

```
auto i_num = {1};
printf("%x\n", i_num); //58a74744
printf("%x\n", &i_num); //58a74730
printf("%x\n", i_num.begin()); //58a74730
```

Comment: Or part of the address.  Or something different entirely, depending on how the platform defines `initializer_list`.  In short, it's at least unspecified, and probably undefined.

Answer (score 9):

One is an `integer` other one an `std::initializer_list<int>`:

```
auto var_auto = {1};
std::cout << typeid(var_auto).name() << std::endl;//St16initializer_listIiE

int var_int = {1};
std::cout << typeid(var_int).name() << std::endl;//i
```

The expression `{1}` defines an initializer list. This is assigned to the auto variable. Remove the "=" to get your expectation.

```
auto var_auto{1};
std::cout << typeid(var_auto).name() << std::endl;//i
```